# Minimum app size using phonegap on android

Tags: android, html, cordova

If my html5-based web-application size (including all html, css, javascript, xml) is 50KB, what will be minimum size of my app if I simply wrap it with phone-gap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had almost 500kb of files including 72kB jquery.mobile.css and the 200 kB Cordova JavaScript file and my application is around 315 kB.

In your case if you consider Cordova Javascript file it should be around 200kB.

**Though you can just compile and check, it will be faster that way.**

Comment: We are taking the decision of using phonegap based on what will be the minimum app size, as our target audience's phone may not have more than a certain capacity. So, please let me know what size installable you ended up with. Thanks

Comment: I just compiled a sample application using PhoneGap and it included a 1kB html file and a 203kB Cordova.js

The resulting APK was 202 kB. From this I can guess that it will be equal to the sum of your file and the Cordova file. The version I am using is PhoneGap 2.5.0

If you use an earlier version I believe the size there is smaller you can check the sizes here http://phonegap.com/download/ and then factor the size of the Cordova/PhoneGap js in your 50kB and that will be the approximate size of your application.